# Core of a subgroup and Norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have recently faced to a notion called the [Norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(group)) of a group. What is the relasion between Norm and [Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group)) of a subgroup of a finite group? Can we say that for every subgroup, the Core is contained in the Norm? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily the case that the core of a subgroup is contained in the Norm of the parent group.  For an example, consider $H = A_{5}$, the alternating group of degree $5$, and take $G = H\times C_{2}$, where $C_2$ is cyclic of order $2$.  Here, the Norm of $G$ has order $2$ but, since $H$ is normal in $G$, we have $H_{G} = H$.

Comment: I , initially, thought that the structure of the Norm is very similar to the Core. Is it a kernel of a certain action?

Comment: @NancyRutkowskie. It is, but not a very interesting one.  Since the norm $N$ of a group $G$ is normal in $G$, it is the kernel of the action of $G$ on the cosets of $N$ by translations. I suppose that is a kind of answer to the first part of your question (as $N=N_G$).

Comment: Sorry James, but can the Norm be a maximal subgroup among the ones which nomalize every subgroups of `G` for example?

Comment: @NancyRutkowskie. If I understand the question, then I think the answer would be yes, for any abelian group $G$.